# Django Redis-Queue pass result from background job into html

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, redis

My small Django project only has one view. The user can enter some options and press *submit*, hence commiting the job that takes >3 minutes. I use [redis-queue](https://python-rq.org/docs/) to carry out the jobs via a background process - the web process simply returns (and renders the .html). All this works. **Question is, how can I pass the background's result (filename of file do be downloaded) after completion back into the html so I can display a download button?**

I guess I would have to put a small *Java / jQuery* script into the .html that keeps polling if the job has completed or not (perhaps making use of RQ's *on_success / on_failure* functions?). However, I'm unsure about the approach. Searching the matter has brought no success ([simular issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126366/django-how-to-use-asynchronous-task-queue-with-celery-and-redis)). Could anyone guide me as to what's the correct way of doing this? I do not intend to use Celery. Ideal solution would be the one providing some code or a clear path. Here's a stripped example:

*view.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ScriptParamForm
from .queue_job import my_job

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.POST.get("btn_submit"):
            req_dict = dict(request.POST)         
            form     = ScriptParamForm(request.POST)
            context['form'] = form

            if form.is_valid():
                req_dict = dict(request.POST)
                job = my_job(outdir=tmp_dir, **req_dict)
                context['job'] = job
            return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', context)

        elif request.POST.get("btn_download"):
            serve_file = request.POST.get("btn_download")

            with open(serve_file, 'rb') as fp:
                response = HttpResponse(fp, headers={
                    'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
                    'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{serve_file}"'
                })
                return response
    else:
        form = ScriptParamForm()
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', context)
```

*home.html*

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST" autocomplete="on">
    {% csrf_token %}
     
    <!-- FORM FIELDS -->
    ...

    <!-- SUBMIT / DOWNLOAD BUTTONS -->
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>

        {% if serve_file %}
        <button type="submit" name="btn_download" value={{serve_mode}} class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
        {% endif %}
        
        <span class="not-visible" id="calc-msg"> This may take a few, relax! :) </span>
    </div>

</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

*main.js*

```js
var x = document.getElementById("btn-submit")

console.log(x)
x.onclick = function () {
    $("#calc-msg").removeClass("not-visible");
    setInterval(function(){blink()}, 1000);
};

function blink() {
    $("#calc-msg").fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways with different advantages and disadvantages each.

The simplest approach is exactly as you mentioned: polling. The disadvantages of polling are:

- it's not real time (you'll get your result no sooner than on your next poll request)
- it doesn't scale so well. This is only a problem is you have many clients all waiting for their results at the same time. For example: 100k clients polling once every 5 seconds = 20k requests per second to the server.

The major advantage is the simplicity of implementation.

Alternatives for real-time are `long polling`, `websockets`, and `webrtc data channels`. The first is all but obsolete, the second is what I'd recommend, the last is sort of an abuse of a protocol that exists but isn't intended for this purpose (it works none the less!). `Websockets` and `webrtc` both provide 2-way communication between your browser and the server. The server can `push` a message to your browser which listens to reacts on these events. Due to the synchronous req/res model of Django, it's not capable of using either out of the box so you'd need to look into `django-channels` or even replace django completely with something like `aiohttp` or `fastapi`.

Assuming that you don't need real-time feed back and that you're not serving your app to 10s of thousands of users I'd suggest you stick will polling.

###### High level overview:

1. Client makes a request.
2. Server creates a "Job" record with a unique identifier and immediately returns this identifier to the client as well as pushing your reqis-queue message. Let's say that a "Job" has 3 possible states: `pending` / `finished` / `failed`.

```py
class Job(models.Model):
    PENDING = 0
    FINISHED = 1
    FAILED = 2
    state = models.IntegerField(default=Job.PENDING)
    result_path = models.CharField(default=None, null=True)
```

In your view, create an instance and pass the identifier to the queue:

```py
job_instance = Job.objects.create()
req_dict = dict(request.POST)
job = my_job(outdir=tmp_dir, job_id=job_instance.id, **req_dict)
context['job'] = job
context['job_id'] = job_instance.id
```

3. The client uses this identifier to poll for the results. As long as the `Job` is still `pending` it should continue requesting updates to the server.

```js
let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
  fetch('your-url.com/job-poll/{job_id}.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.job.state === 1) { // finished
          // download {data.job.result_path} and
          clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else if (data.job.state === 2) { // failed
          // tell the user
          clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else { // pending
          // job is still pending, do nothing.
      }
    })
}, 3000)
```

A new view to handle the polling:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def job_poll(request, job_id):
    j = Job.objects.get(id=job_id)
    return JsonResponse({
      "job": {
        "state": j.state,
        "result_path": j.result_path,
      },
    })
```

4. When the redis-queue worker is finished, it should update the Job record with the final state: `finished` or `failed`

```py
j = Job.objects.get(id=job_id)
j.state = Job.FINISHED
j.result_path = '...'
j.save()
```

5. Finally on the next poll request, your client will now be aware of the finished job and can now download the result, error message, etc.

(note: all code is pseudo code, nothing was tested here)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great explanation, deeply appreciated! I will attempt to implement the solution and if appropriate mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I tried the solution but couldn't figure out how to properly use the java snippet. Do I have to explicitly call *myInterval* somehow from the HTML?